# Desktop Software for maintaining Codes

Tags: software-recommendation

Im finding difficulty in maintaining my code. I usually use C, PHP, Unix Script and Matlab Script for my development. I tried versioning my code as filename_v1, filename_v2 etc But its very confusing and i face difficulty in the understanding which code i used some 3 days back and also facing problem to find out which version of code produced the output which im analyzing.

Is there any desktop software to maintain my code datewise so that i wont create multiple version of my code?
If not, can anyone guide me how people overcome this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using a [source code management system (SCM) like `git`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Git). Using `gitk` or `git gui`, there's also graphical user interface available ([more on GUIs for git](http://tombuntu.com/index.php/2011/11/26/graphical-git-clients-for-ubuntu/)). Furthermore, most IDE's (integrated development environments) support accessing `git` repositories.

Using `git` (or an other source code management system like `svn`), you don't need to create multiple version of your code; everything is managed by the scm. You can easily change between different versions of your files.

Answer (score 2):

Better use any versioning system, you dont have to manually name your files like filename_v1, filename_v2 etc.

There are already solutions available to maintain versioning of your code repositories. Use any version control system of your choice.

Try [Subversion(SVN)](http://subversion.apache.org/) OR [CVS](http://cvs.nongnu.org/)

They will time-stamp your code, track changes, and do versioning.

Comment: Do they store the files locally or upload to the internet?

Comment: they store the file in repositories, you can create the repository in your local or in network or make it publicly available over internet

Comment: SVN and CVS are pretty outdated these days. While SVN is still used in corporate settings, and many older projects still use it, you would be better served learning one of the main three new distributed version control systems - Git, Bazaar, and Mercurial.